# Setting array key

Tags: php

So in a simple matter, I need to take first array's values from nested array and apply to another array's keys. Currently, I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
   Array
   (
       [0] => item-name
       [1] => item-description
       [2] => listing-id
       [3] => price
   )
   Array
   (
       [0] => item which is very nice
       [1] => an explicitly nice array
       [2] => 0019001
       [3] => 99.95
   )
   Array
   (
       [0] => item which is not nice
       [1] => an explicitly not nice item
       [2] => 0000001
       [3] => 9.95
   )
)
```

and I want to have a result that looks like this:

```
Array
(
   Array
   (
       [item-name] => item which is very nice
       [item-description] => an explicitly nice array
       [listing-id] => 0019001
       [price] => 99.95
   )
   Array
   (
       [item-name] => item which is not nice
       [item-description] => an explicitly not nice item
       [listing-id] => 0000001
       [price] => 9.95
   )
)
```

Tried using **array_map**, but didn't manage to get myself anywhere with it. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, the first sub-array is the list of keys, and then the following sub-arrays are all of the values? You can use a `for`/`foreach` loop to iterate over your array and construct your new output array.

Comment: It would make more sense creating a new array than trying to modify the existing one through `array_map`. A simple `foreach` and `array_combine` could do the job.

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question by editing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start= [
    ['item-name', 'item-description', 'listing-id', 'price'],
    ['item which is very nice', 'an explicitly nice array', '0019001', 99.95],
    ['item which is not nice', 'an explicitly not nice item', '0000001', 9.95]
];

$keys = array_values($start[0]);

$counted = count($start);
for ( $i=1; $i < $counted; $i++) {
    foreach($keys as $j => $key){
        $t[$key] = $start[$i][$j];
    }
    $new[] = $t;
}
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item-name] => item which is very nice
            [item-description] => an explicitly nice array
            [listing-id] => 0019001
            [price] => 99.95
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item-name] => item which is not nice
            [item-description] => an explicitly not nice item
            [listing-id] => 0000001
            [price] => 9.95
        )
)
```

Or, to be slightly more concise using some of the builtin array functions

```
//shift the first occurance off $start and place in $keys
$keys = array_shift($start);

//now the $start array does not contain the occ with fields names in
//so you can look the array from the beginning and add values to names
//making a new array

foreach ($start as $values) {
    $new[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep this simple. So first you get the first entry of your array. and then you just run over the rest of the array, creating the new array:

```
$keys = array_shift($rawData);
foreach ($rawData as $values) {
    $newArray[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```

And you're done. See: [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)